# how can i move my database content(post) from pbnl database to wordpress database?

Tags: phpmyadmin

i just move my site from php to wordpress, and i want to my move all my forum content from the pbnl site to the wordpress, how can i do thta?

the php table is  b_topic are the structures/column are 
`id`, `forumid`, `message`, `subject`, `poster`, `date`, `lastposter`, `lastpostdate`, `replies`, `hints`, `locked`

while the wordpress structures/columns are

`ID`, `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`, `post_excerpt`, `post_status`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`, `post_password`, `post_name`, `to_ping`, `pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`, `post_content_filtered`, `post_parent`, `guid`, `menu_order`, `post_type`, `post_mime_type`, `comment_count`

your suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Will you be using a forum plugin such as [BBPress](https://codex.bbpress.org/getting-started/importing-data/import-forums/) for WP? If so, it uses it's own tables, not `wp_posts`. Your best bet is to go through a CSV/XML export/import.

Comment: tanks for your reply, am nt using a forum plugin, am using wordpress category, and any new post i publish gos to wp_posts

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Can you create an RSS feed with all your data? Then you could use RSS [Import](https://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content). Does PBNL have any export functions?

Comment: Tanks kenney,...d wordpress is running with a workingworking rss feed,..but the pbnl site is currently not runnig,...have change d site to wordpress, but i still have d datebase on a different user namr,...so wat i want to do now is to move some of my data from the pbnl_database to wp_database